# Run a windows command line utility allowing it to display its output to screen AND loggin it to file.txt

Tags: command-line, batch-file, logging, stdout

i have a utility i want to run which does not allow logging in the options/arguments of the program itself.
I can naturally run the program with a > logfile.txt
However, i would like to see the status of the program while it is running.
So i.e. if i pipe it , then it does not update stdout.
I know in unix you can use tee to allow stdout and log.
Must be a way in windows which is not over complicated.

Comment: [Same question on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/796476/displaying-windows-command-prompt-output-and-redirecting-it-to-a-file)

Comment: To expand on the above comment, you can indeed use PowerShell,and there is a `Start-Transcript` function for this purpose

Comment: `Start-Transcript` is great; just remember to `Stop-Transcript` when you're done.